# How to install pcs 4x100 14 rims on pcd 4x113 of the same 14 inch rims?

Tags: tires, wheels

The pcd size of Maruti Zen is 4x113 of 14 inch rims. The 113 is measured in millimetres. So, comparing the above pcd with another pcd of 4x100 14 inch rims gives a difference of just 13 millimetres which is almost negligible!!!

Since the unit being millimetres, will a 14 inch rims 4x100 fits on 4x113 without extra spacers or adapters? Just 13 mm difference.......

Comment: Almost negligible but **NOT negligible**.

Answer (score 3):

No, 4x100 wheels will not fit on a car with 4x113 hubs - each bolt will be 6.5mm out from the hole it needs to go through, and to fit properly the bolts need to be exactly centred in the holes.

Comment: But difference is just 14 mm I terms of millimetres.....if it was inches tis no way possible. Now, only millimetres...

Comment: 14 mm is over .5 inches

Comment: @ThangTons I agree, 14mm **is** negligible when measuring from Paris to London... but when on a pcd of 113 compared to 100 then it is more than significant.

Comment: If you can't fit bolts in holes that are half and inch out of alignment, you just need to buy a bigger hammer ;)

Answer (score 0):

To go from one bolt pattern to another you could in theory use a *bolt-on spacer*. They look like this:

[image]

The spacer has holes where the original studs fit, you use original lug nuts there, then bolt your wheels to the spacers.

The problem with these is they would offset the wheels a good amount away from their normal position, so in a typical car you are likely to have the tires contacting fenders.

When you are going from a smaller to a larger bolt pattern (4x100 wheels on a 4x113 vehicle for instance) there are two more issues to consider:

1. *Center bore* for smaller bolt patterns is usually smaller. This means the wall of the spacer must necessarily be pretty thin which isn't ideal.
2. The wheels using a larger bolt pattern are generally rated for higher load. You may be using wheels that aren't rated for the weight of your car.

With that said it seems that 4x100 -> 4x113 spacers are in fact manufactured and sold.